# SQL automatic insert ID's from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables (in Joomla, MySQL)

**Table 1** *jos_users*

```
id | name | etc..

62 | Foo

63 | Bar
```

---

**Table 2** jos_user_usergroup_map

```
user_id | group_id

62 | 2

63 | 2
```

---

Can I through PhpMyAdmin

Select ALL id's from **jos_users** and insert them into **jos_user_undergroup_map** (user_id) with the value "2" in the field group_id

Thanks!

Comment: In what way is this `automatic`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into jos_user_undergroup_map (user_id, group_id)
select id, 2 from jos_users
```

Comment: That did the trick!! Thank you so much :) It is around 3000 rows so it would take a while to do it manually :)